XLDeploy delete udm.DeploymentPackage in curl/python
I'm trying to auto clean deployment Packages that are too old and not deployed.
I managed to get a list of udm.DeploymentPackage with all their artifacts associated and the docker image. I managed to delete theses with our Artifactory (Jfrog) with some python requests.
The only missing step, is to delete the udm.DeploymentPackage, and I can not find any documentation that says how to remove the Package.
So I've openned up the Chrome DevTool tab and checked the Network.
When deleting a Package, I get this curl.
curl 'https://xldeploy.xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/xldeploy/repository/ci/Applications%2FTEAM%2FAPI%2Fproject%2Fmy-package-name' \
  -X 'DELETE' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: fr-FR,fr;q=0.9' \
  -H 'Accept-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Cookie: HttpOnly; HttpOnly; HttpOnly; HttpOnly; SESSION_XLD=xxxxxxxxxxxx; XSRF-TOKEN=xxxxxxxxxxxx' \
  -H 'Origin: https://xldeploy.xxxxxxxxxxxx.net' \
  -H 'Referer: https://xldeploy.xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors' \
  -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/125.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'X-XSRF-TOKEN: XXXXXXXXXX' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="125", "Chromium";v="125", "Not.A/Brand";v="24"' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0' \
  -H 'sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"'

I tried to simplify the query using an Auth Token in curl:
curl 'https://xldeploy.xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/xldeploy/repository/ci/Applications%2FTEAM%2FAPI%2Fproject%2Fmy-package-name' \
    -X 'DELETE' \
    -H 'Accept: application/json' \
    --header "Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

I get no response, no error code. But the package is not deleted.
When I do the same in python:
url = f"curl 'https://xldeploy.xxxxxxxxxxxx.net/xldeploy/repository/ci/Applications%2FTEAM%2FAPI%2Fproject%2Fmy-package-name"
print(f"DELETE XLD {url}")
response = requests.delete(url,
        headers={
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Authorization": f"Basic {XLD_AUTH_TOKEN}",
        },
        proxies={"http": None, "https": None},
        verify=False,
    )
print(response)

I print the correct URL, because when I click on it, I can see all the content linked to the package (artifacts).
But I get an error 500, and the package is not deleted.
How do you manage to simply delete a Package in curl?

I found the solution:
curl -k --noproxy '*' -X DELETE https://XXXXX/deployit/repository/ci/Applications%2FTEAM%2FAPI%2Fproject%2Fmy-package-name \
    --header "Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxx"


Documentation: https://apidocs.digital.ai/xl-deploy/22.0.x/rest-api/com.xebialabs.deployit.engine.api.RepositoryService.html#/repository/ci/{ID:.+}:DELETE
The difference is that one is deployit (API) and the other one xldeploy (UI)
